# Can Shaitaan mimic Peace i.e., can he give us a false sense of peace/tranquility or is peace/tranquility from Allah (swt) only?

Tags: allah, shaitan, waswasa

Sometimes I ask Allah to send sakinah/peace in my heart for something that I'm praying for & He sends it and I immediately feel at peace but sometimes when I ask for sakinah/peace again for the same thing because of uneasiness in my chest, I do not get it so I ask Him if the opposite is true (opposite of what I'm asking) and then I feel like at peace for the complete opposite happening. So here I am wondering if Satan can give us a false sense of peace to cause us distress etc because he knows what we're asking from Allah. How do I know what feeling is from Allah and what feeling is not?

I'm just really, really confused. Any sort of guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes the devil can give false peace. Satan encourages and brings people closer to sin with the promise of peace and well-being, and in the same way turns man away from what God has placed in true peace. The peace that Satan gives to sinful man is like drugs. It gives the consumer peace and well-being for a moment, but the drug user does not know that this peace is false, and then the anxiety multiplies.

Do not play with your feelings. It is better to discover the root of your worries and solve the problem from the root. Prevention is better than cure.
Most of our anxieties are the result of the devil's whispers.It is enough to observe God's piety in every decision in your life. Then God has promised in the Qur'an:
Whoever is wary of Allah, He shall make for him a way out [of the adversities of the world and the Hereafter].65_v 2,3.